# Which rest end point call when session getting timeout in office online?

Tags: office365, ms-wopi

We have integrate Office Online with our application and implement necessary rest end points in our application which are defined in Office Online documentation [WOPI REST Documentation](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/) and all working fine.

But problem is that when Access token getting timeout from office online then it will not call any rest end point.

Is there any rest end point which intimate our application that your session getting timed out for current document?

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the [`access_token_ttl`](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/concepts.html#term-access-token-ttl)? Are you setting it correctly? It is represented as the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 UTC. You may also set it to 0 to see whether the problem persists.

The only endpoint for refreshing tokens is [`GetNewAccessToken`](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/bootstrapper/GetNewAccessToken.html) which is not required for most of the devices. In most cases Office Online will simply prompt users to save and refresh their sessions if the access token for their session is close to expiring.

Comment: Yes, i already set access_token_ttl and it give me prompt when session is close to expiring. And once session expired then it again give session expired message. But how my application identify that for this document session was expired?

Comment: GetNewAccessToken this end point is used for Android or IOS application but our application is web based and we have pass access_token from our side.

Comment: @rocky Facing Same issue , like when I click on Refresh button on Wopi Client, It does not give back any call

Comment: As I said, there is no general concept of an endpoint for refreshing tokens. I suggest you set the token ttl to a longer period (e.g. several hours) and scope the access token to a single user and resource combination.